# When I cough... How to prevent wrong recognition in SpeechRecognitionEngine?

Tags: c#, grammar, voice, speech

When I load a grammar and use:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine _sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
...
_sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

And I blow or cough or say any other word (doh! for example) on the  microphone,I get a false positive. For example:

If i say to mic: "Doh!" (like homer...)

RecognizeText: "yes"
Confidence score: 0.8639852

About grxml... Weight is not working as I expected for my "WakeUpWord".

It is possible to add confidence to my grxml file?

Is there any way to prevent a false positive with SpeechRecognitionEngine in C#?

I've tried the follow grammar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" version="1.0" root="yesOrNo">
    <rule id="yesOrNo">
      <one-of>
        <item>yes</item>
        <item>no</item>
      </one-of>
    </rule>
  </grammar>
```

Comment: Did you ever round a solución for this? I'll probably be working with speech recognition and this could help me.

Answer (score 0):

There not an easy way to prevent this. Either you put an very good VAD (Voice activity detector) prior to the ASR system, or you add an alternative rule to your yesno rule containing all possible sequences of phones transcribed as silence.